# Linking or embedding K2 Items

Tags: joomla2.5

I have created a k2 category of say trainers. I have then created K2 items and linked them to the trainer category. The k2 items are bios. A picture and blurb of text.

All is well.

Now I have an "article" say about Physical Rehab. This is a K2 item linked to it's respective category. At the end of the "article" I want to embed / link a specific trainer bio rather than retype everything. Further if I make a correction it propegates.

Now when I say article above I don't think I am using the term in the Joomla context accurately.

I say this because my Google search terms led me to Article Anywhere plugin. I installed it thinking I had this beat....only it didn't work. When I went to embed a bio it wasn't there. Hardly anything was and I suspect this is due to my K2 items not being "articles"

So I'm not so worried about the plug-in as much as how can I go about linking, chaining, embedding etc. my k2 items so I don't have a bunch of repetitive code?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When referring to content in Joomla:

Items = article in K2
Articles = articles in Joomla com_content

When you use an extension that refers to articles, they mean the built in Joomla com_content. Articles Anywhere doesn't pull data from K2 items.

You probably need this - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/k2-extensions/19641